# Running Teamspeak server at startup and shutting down teamspeak at shutdown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown, init, teamspeak

I'm new to linux, and i have a Teamspeak 3 server on a Ubuntu server. I would like to make the server auto start and stop when the system boots and shuts down. I understand that i need to make scripts in the /etc/init. My question is how would i write such a script? I'm trying to make it nice and simple. Below is what I have written to try to make this possible.

inside /etc/init i have a file called teamspeak3.conf, in that file I have the following

script
     start
          /home/teamspeak3-user/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh start

```
 stop
      /home/teamspeak3-user/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh stop
```

end script

Is this right? Ive done some reading and i just don't understand what to do. I'm completely lost. Thanks guys.

Comment: No need to stop the server before shutting down - if the computer is off, so is the TS server!  To get an autostart, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).

Comment: But I would rather shut the server down gracefully than force a shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a script located in `/etc/init.d/` then you are pretty much set to go.

Issue one of these commands (depending on your system).

> systemctl enable myscript
>
> chkconfig myscript on

When you issue the shutdown command, a `SIGTERM` is sent to all running process, and is the default graceful shutdown command.

The server should handle that on its own.